# RegEx - Linking an URL in a html text

Tags: html, regex, url, hyperlink, anchor

Imagine the following string

```html
http://somedomain.com
<p>http://somedomain.com</p>
<a href="http://somedomain.com">http://somedomain.com</a>
```

I need a function or regular expression that would convert it into.

```
<a href="http://somedomain.com">http://somedomain.com</a>
<p><a href="http://somedomain.com">http://somedomain.com</a></p>
<a href="http://somedomain.com">http://somedomain.com</a>
```

The problem is that every solution I found would break the already linked url on the third line, or not link the url in the `<p>` tag.

PHP solution would be nice, but is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex that passes your test cases - it's .Net syntax I'm afraid, rather than PHP

```
(?<=(?:[^a-z0-9]|^))(?<!href=["'])([a-z0-9]+:\/\/[^\s<>\(\)\[\]'"]+)(?=[\s<>\(\)\[\]'"])(?!</a>)
```

And the replacement string:

```
<a href='$1'>$1</a>
```

**Breakdown and Explantion**

The regex is made up of 5 parts:

1. `(?<=(?:[^a-z0-9]|^))`

   - Positive look behind assertion - the url is preceeded by a non-protocol character (or is the start of the string)
2. `(?<!href=["'])`

   - negative look behind assertion - url isn't preceded by an href attribute
3. `([a-z0-9]+:\/\/[^\s<>\(\)\[\]'"]+)`

   - Captures the URL
   - Bracketed group, so we can use it in the replacement expression
   - This is a very simple URL matching expression - protocol, followed by `://`, followed by one or more "non-URL" characters. You might want to replace it with something better.
4. `(?=[\s<>\(\)\[\]'"])`

   - Positive lookahead assertion - url is followed by a non-url character
5. `(?!</a>)`

   - Negative lookahead assertion - url isn't followed by a closing `</a>` tag

Comment: It works. For php preg_replace I only needed to change it to.
@(?<=(?:[^a-z0-9]))(?<!href=["\'])([a-z0-9]+:\/\/[^\s<>\(\)\[\]\'"]+)(?=[\s<>\(\)\[\]\'"])(?!</a>)@
note that i removed the |^ in the first part, because php does not support look behind assertions of non fixed length. But it still works, even with the link starting at the beginning of the text.